# R takes too long to generate sequence of dates

Tags: r

I have to generate about 45000 sequence of dates by month based on an ending date and the number of months since the beginning. Then I have to move the dates  to the closest one in an other vector (which doesn't have to be of the same  length). I'm using the `lubridate` function `%m-%` to add the number of months I need in an `lapply` and then using `findInterval` to move the dates based on the other vector. The problem I have is that it takes too long, like 2.5 minutes in my laptop and I have to do this multiple times. Is there a way to speed up the process with out paralleling it?

This is an example of my code:

```
library(lubridate)
vec_ayuda = sort(seq(Sys.Date(),length.out = 50000,by = "day")[sample(1:50000,48000)])
Vencimiento = seq(Sys.Date(),length.out = 45000,by = "day")
plazo = runif(45000,15,230)
fechas = lapply(1:length(Vencimiento),function(x)
  sort(Vencimiento[x]%m-%months(c(1:(plazo[x]))-1)))
res_lista = lapply(fechas,function(x) 
  as.matrix(x[findInterval(x,vec_ayuda)]))
```

The variable `fechas` will have a list with sequence of dates. The input to generate them are a vector of dates (in `as.Date` format which are in the variable `Vencimiento`) and a vector witht the number of months since beginning which are in the variable `plazo`.

The variable `res_lista` will also have a list with sequence of dates. The input to generate them are a list of original dates (in this case the variable `fechas`) and a vector with other dates (`vec_ayuda`) which will determine the new position of sequence of dates in the list `fechas`.

Comment: Could you make a bit clearer what are the expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: @sindri_baldur I added an explanation of the main functions of the code so it is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following to generate `fechas` will be faster:

```
fechas <- mapply(seq, from=Vencimiento, by="-1 month", length.out=plazo, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: Took me a will to realize that the result from your answer is not completely correct. When a sequence of dates have to contain the last day of February it will end up having the first day of march